# Is there a downside to using a custom hook as a store instead of tools like redux or useReducer?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Just like the title, I am wondering if I could use a simple hook to save data which can be used by any consumer

```
export default () => ({data: 'some random data'})
```

And any consumer can use it like so

```
const { data } = useSomeDataStore()
```

If we want to make the data updatable, I can add a setter to it like so:

```
export default () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('some random data')

  return {
    data,
    setData
  }
}
```

So I am wondering, why do we need ContextAPI, redux and a thousand other state management tools? I understand that for complex and data intensive app, we might need some of these tools to manage it, but for a very simple app design, what are the downsides of this implementation?

Comment: The downside is that it doesn't work. That hook will allow you to reuse *code* but not data. Every component that calls the hook will be creating it's *own* state variable, not a shared one.

Comment: Your updatable example is just a wrapper around `useState`. It will work and behave the exact same way as using `useState` directly would.